# Proper way converting TorchScript Version to Core ML

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I'm trying to convert `PyTorch ml model` into `Core ML`. As shown in this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/10154/), I first converted it to `TorchScript Version`.

But the problem happens when converting `TorchScript Version` to `Core ML`.

As first, I did as follow:

```
import coremltools as ct

model = ct.convert(
    traced_model,
    inputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=input_ids.shape), ct.TensorType(shape=attention_mask.shape)],
    outputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=decoder_input_ids.shape)]
 )
```

But it was giving me an error saying:

```
ValueError: The 'shape' argument must not be specified for the outputs, since it is automatically inferred from the input shapes and the ops in the model
```

So I used following code for converting it to `Core ml`:

```
import coremltools as ct

model = ct.convert(
    traced_model,
    inputs=[ct.TensorType(shape=input_ids.shape), ct.TensorType(shape=attention_mask.shape), ct.TensorType(shape=decoder_input_ids.shape)]
 )
```

This time code block ran successfully, but when I actually downloaded the converted coreml, it was not detecting decoder_input_ids as one of inputs like following:

[image]

How can I fix this problem, and what am I doing wrong? Btw the model is Seq2Seq model